# Something mysterious happening?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem related with this code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 void main() 
 {
        char array[0];
        scanf("%s", array);
        printf("%s", array);
        return;
 }
```

when I enter data in input-field it get store in array and output is obtained but it's size is 0.

and another thing happens is that when I enter suppose 'a' 12-times then somehow controls reaches to `scanf()` for taking input and again on entering 'a' 12-times control again reaches to `scanf()` and this goes on until I enter less than 12 character.

if on entering greater than 12 characters the program crashes.

Why this happens?

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your compiler should generate an error message, a size of `0` is a constraints violation.

Comment: @Olaf - not necessarily - GCC provides zero-length arrays as *compiler-specific* extension... However, writing to such an array still remains undefined behaviour (except if having been casted from correctly allocated larger memory).

Comment: @Aconcagua: The question does not state which compiler it is, thus the code **does** invoke UB. Even with that superfluous extension, the code invokes UB for dereferencing an invalid pointer address.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `int main(void)`...

Answer (score 5):

A statement like

```
 char array[0];
```

is invalid code as per ISO C. It's a pure constraints violation. The size has to be greater than 0.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2 (*emphasis mine*)

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static`, the `[` and `]` may delimit
>   an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
>   expression shall have an integer type. **If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero.** [...]

That said,

- `void main()` is not a conforming signature for hosted environment. It needs to be `int main(void)` at least to be standard compliant.
- while using `scanf()` and family, always

  - limit the length of input by providing maximum field width, something like

    ```
    char input [10] = {0};
    scanf("%9s", input);
    ```
  - check the return value to ensure the success of the call.

Comment: @AmanWarudkar what is this? random experiment? Read the basics and know beforehand what you try to achieve. Just because you can type in anything, does not make it a valid code, anyways.

Comment: ok then on setting size of array to 1 the above picture goes on entering character a 13 times.

Comment: @AmanWarudkar You need to provide sufficient buffer to hold the input you want to scan, e. g. `char array[32];`. Additionally, you *absolutely* should prevent scanf from writing beyound this buffer: `scanf("%31s", array);`.

Comment: @AmanWarudkar read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you have one in your code.

Comment: Ok thanks BROTHER now i understand. what's going on with this code.

Comment: Please create an MCVE which only shows the remaining problems you have. I.e. incorporate answers and comments, then elaborate on the 12/13 character issue.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: If only beginners would read the basics before asking ... (sidenote: OP did not change the dimension, but the length of the array in the (only) dimension).

Comment: @AmanWarudkar and changing the array size to 1 in this case also invokes UB, as for a 1-element char array, %s will infer out of bound memory access leading to UB

Comment: Hey i have find a way to fix it by using "SEARCH SETS".  scanf(%[^\n], &array);

Comment: @AmanWarudkar that's even worse....don't do that. Learn C by careful study and practice, not by random experiment.